# Insert Action from UIButton on IB not displaying in Xcode 8.1 & 8.2, just Outlet & Outlet Collection

Tags: swift, xcode, ibaction, iboutlet

[image]This is a remanent bug that has been around in several majors versions of Xcode and it seems Apple don't care.

Collecting tricks from other related issues my workaround is running this script & resetting `Simulator`->`Content and settings...` but it does not always work

```
#!/bin/sh
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode
rm -rf "$(getconf DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR)/org.llvm.clang/ModuleCache"
rm -rf ~/library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
```

I suspect there is a problem with the index caused by some name reusing due copy-pasting files as while the index is being built I can see the `Insert Action, Outlet` dialog but upon clicking on `save` it refuses to do so saying `it has no information about that class`.

Xcode Version 8.1 (8B62), Simulator Version 10.0 (SimulatorApp-700.14 CoreSimulator-307.14.2) edited: same with Version 8.2 (8C38)

The problem is that creating the outlet programmatically like

```
@IBAction func myAction(_ sender: AnyObject) { }
```

and pretend to connect the blue circle with any control on the Storyboard doesn't work neither as the control is not highlighted in blue as usual.

It's cumbersome to being adding outlets and adding target actions manually as workaround as I have been doing for weeks so any help on how to clean the project is welcome. I already tried the check-uncheck `target membership` to clean any bogus reference on each file with no difference.

The functionality on other projects works just fine

Comment: Please describe the issue more detailed an add more information regarding your setup (Xcode version, used simulator...).

Comment: He mentioned xcode8.1